# Problems when opening Bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In the current project that I am working on, when I open modal and close it the html page shrinks in addition when the modal appears the scroll bar gets disabled and does not appear even when the modal closes and hence I can't scroll my page.

Further when the scrollbar disappears that parts appears blank which I don't want.

Here are the snapshots after opening the modal the scrollbar disappears

[image]

after closing the page shrinks

[image]

I am adding the modal inside a navbar. the modal does not show any of these problems when the navbar component is run is individually. The snapshot of that picture is below

Here I am opening the modal and that is not causing the page to shrink

[image]

after closing the modal

[image]

the code is available in this link

i have linked header and index.. https://github.com/darshanhosahalli/example/blob/master/header.jsp https://github.com/darshanhosahalli/example/blob/master/index.jsp –

This is the code that I have used

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <!------------ Modal Header -------------------->
      <div id="modal-header" class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">Sign In</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <form action="login" method="post">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label id="modallbl" for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
               <label id="modallbl" for="pwd">Password:</label>
               <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password">
             </div>
             <button id="modalButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
               <SPAN class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" ></SPAN>                     Sign In
             </button>
             <div id="chkbox" class="checkbox">
                <label id="modallbl1"><input type="checkbox">Stay Signed in</label>
             </div>
         </form>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hello, @darshan. Please provide more of your code. It would be nice to have your ```index.html``` and also the ```styles.css```

Comment: _"I am adding the modal inside a navbar."_ I wouldn't recommend this. Usually the best place for modal markup is just before the closing `</body>` tag. Since a modal has to be displayed on top int shouldn't be nested inside any other markup

Comment: I see one extra closing div. More code please.

Comment: Provide complete code please! whole page html and css!

Comment: i have linked header and index.. https://github.com/darshanhosahalli/example/blob/master/header.jsp https://github.com/darshanhosahalli/example/blob/master/index.jsp

Comment: @zgood i tried it, still the problem is persisting.

Comment: You need to show all relevant markup _here_, and you need to show rendered HTML, not server-side templating code.